# Can I tell typescript that an interface is actually implemented?

Tags: typescript

I have a pretty big REST API that I consume from an Angular App and I would like to migrate to code generation. It is working fine in another project with OpenAPI client generators.

I do not want to make my life harder than necessary and therefore I have to extend the generated interfaces for my response objects to be compatible with the existing code. Unfortunantely it is not possible in typescript to write extension methods for interfaces. Therefore I was thinking about a workaround.

The idea is to create a simple wrapper class for my models.

Lets say I have the following response:

```
interface FooResponse {
    test: number;
}
```

I would create a model for it like this:

```
class Model {
    constructor(source: object) {
        for (var property in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                (this as any)[property] = source[property];
            }
        }

        Object.freeze(this);
    }
}

// ERROR: Class 'FooModel' incorrectly implements interface 'FooResponse'.
// Property 'test' is missing in type 'FooModel' but required in type 'FooResponse'.
class FooModel extends Model implements FooResponse {
    constructor(source: object) {
        super(source);
    }

    // ERROR: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'FooModel'.
    public get squareTest() {
        return this.test * this.test;
    }
}
```

Also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CUIGcAO6IuKA3gFDJXKS5gBcyIArgLYBG0A3OQL7nkEAGzi5cyALLoAJhCHIK1ZAiJ0ozBGHRQAFLnTMoSRunYArCJoCUCykuoxtyHQDc4UZPijp80MAE9kUGR9QyQbRXso4BhnUKMIADoAC1EAeQB3EAAFb18oAJ0vHz9-Kwi7KKrnMGTgcVFkOBAygG1i-ICAXWQAXjiDBKaGlqt2vNKunmqlfmr+Svs080swRJgoCAgALwgdWvqraep+BeFRcQx0KVl5CAAPSBBpcRu5INZ8IQhWCHBLzA4AiqMiLFTEMDqTTaPSDYzIUwWay2aq4Zj5WFhCBHRYLJT4ZjsITABDIADmEDAIQAjsx3BAACp4MA6CrVTZgQwgGh1XCJWhUgBUPPq-OZxyopyAA

I get two errors as described above in the code sample

- `Class 'FooModel' incorrectly implements interface 'FooResponse'. Property 'test' is missing in type 'FooModel' but required in type 'FooResponse'.`
- `Property 'test' does not exist on type 'FooModel'. (2 times)`

So my question is:

- Can I tell the compiler that my interface is actually implemented?
- Is there a better way to extend the interface?

Comment: But your object don't implements the interface. `test` property isn't declared anywhere, therefore the compiler is warning this.

Comment: Yeah, this is a misuse of classes IMO, though it's understandable if a class is required for your API generator

Comment: @Matthias The Problem is that the generator has bugs generating the classes and that I have custom methods similar to squareTest in my current model classes. I would just like to extend the interface with a nextension method, but it is not possible.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yeas, I know, but at runtime it does implement the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class definitions in Typescript also create an interface of the same name. You can augment that like below. Not sure exactly what's going on, but it tells typescript that the property does exist.

```
interface FooModel extends FooResponse {}
class FooModel extends Model {
    ...
    public get squareTest() {
        return this.test * this.test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this works. Not the best solution at the moment, but I do not have a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
interface FooResponse {
    test: number;
}
interface FooResponseEnhanced extends FooResponse {}

class FooResponseEnhanced {
    constructor (foo: FooResponse) {
        Object.assign(this, foo, {})
    }

    public get squareTest() {
        return this.test * this.test;
    }
}

console.log(new FooResponseEnhanced({test: 2}).squareTest);
```

Yes, you would have to do the extra step of wrapping your responses that need to be extended with special functions, so it's not perfect.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is the same answer as the one above. But thanks a lot for pointing me to the Object.assign method. Have forgotten that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change that interface to an abstract class you can do this

```js
// In this abstract class you can define as many properties as you need
abstract class FooResponse {
    test!: number;
}

// For simplification I would directly use Object.assign without 
// needing a second base-class to inherit from
class FooModel extends FooResponse {
    constructor(source: object) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, source);
    }

    public get squareTest() {
        return this.test * this.test;
    }
}

// Usage example
const fm = new FooModel({test: 6});
const result = fm.squareTest;
console.log(result);
```